# Configuring several environments in WPF/Wix

Tags: c#, wpf, jenkins, .net-core, wix

I have WPF .Net Core application, I use Wix for creating installer and Jenkins as my CI tool.
For now after commit, Jenkins builds Wix project and sends output .msi file wherever I need.

In my application I have **appsettings.json** file that stores my configuration. As you you can guess, I want to have several configuration files, e.g. appsettings.dev.json, appsettings.qa.json for my dev and qa environments.

What is the pretty way to do that?

First of all, I want to detect env by git branch name. It's easy to get this variable in Jenkins, but what do I do next?

First option was having 3 files (one per environment) and use Environment Variable while reading configuration at the start of the app. This requires that Jenkins passes value to Wix (how?) and Wix creates environment variable. I kinda didn't like that way, because it seemed like very old-fashioned. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. Also, I thought that having environment variable is overhead, since it's used by only one, pretty simple, desktop app. And the last problem, we have to keep all 3 files on end user machine.

Second option I tried was having 4 appsettings files (one main file and one per environment). Once Jenkins recognizes environment, it replaces main file with the file that suits the environment (e.g. appsettings.dev.json for dev branch). But it didn't work out: main appsettings file was updated, but when I run the app, I see that settings don't change. I checked that I replace appsettings file before using Wix, but it didn't help.

So, I feel like there is simple way to configure this, can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am not sure that it is perfect solution, but I came up with one way of doing this.
Basically, I made one appsettings.json file containing variable **env** and a section for every environment. When I push a commit CI writes branch name to **env** variable and application uses section called as target branch.
In general, it looks like this:

```
"environment": "dev",
"dev": {...},
"qa": {...}...
```